# Detect the completion of js script files present at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following link http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom says
"Put Scripts at the Bottom" for Speeding Up Your Web Site. Lets say I have added them at bottom

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
...
...
...
html
....
<script src="script1"/>
<script src="script2"/>
<script src="script3"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if I have the requirement to access some function of those js files somewhere in the middle of html, how would I do that? Let's say the code is like this

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    html
    .....
<script>
$('a.test').modal('show);
</script>
    ....
    <script src="script1"/>
    <script src="script2"/>
    <script src="script3"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Above "$", "modal" etc are the part of js libraries attached at the bottom of the page. How will I detect the completion of bottom scripts and fire the code written in script tag (

> $('a.test').modal('show);

)

Comment: They get executed in order. Put them in the order you want.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use attributes and unobtrusive techniques.

Comment: @Christopher how can "$" and "modal" etc are accessible since they are present at bottom of the page and I am trying to attach events somewhere in the middle of that page.

Comment: @Slaks "use attributes an unobtrusive techniques." I didn't get this point.

Comment: Instead of sprinkling Javascript throughout your document, add attributes to instruct the JS at the bottom to do what you want.

Comment: `js files somewhere in the middle of html` What is preventing you from placing that js at the bottom instead of the middle of the html?  That might be an easier problem to solve

Comment: I have different user controls where that middle js code is written

Comment: You've got jQuery already. Use events that way.  Don't hardcode your javascript right into the HTML itself!

Answer (score 0):

To execute a script you have to make sure you have to provided all the necessary dependencies for that script. Hence, you have two options:

1. Put necessary script references before the particular script
2. Put the script at the bottom of the page.

Nothing is set in stone and the real solution depends on your particular problem.

Comment: Can I fire some event when all the bottom scripts are loaded and bind that event on js code present at middle of my page?

Comment: yeah, just wait for the scripts to load before doing the stuff in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Its a general good coding practice to keep all scripts at one portion of html. 
Having said that, i would suggest the same thing, to have maximum of script loading at the bottom, this helps in quick loading. 
As far as dependencies go, if you script is dependent on something, try including it before it is called. Its basically iterative :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to consider your design and what you want to do with your page.

Start with your hypothesis: Putting  tags at the bottom speeds up your website.
Does it speed up your website? not really. So what does it do? The advantage of loading a script at the bottom of the DOM means that the DOM always gets loaded first.

The page is parsed from top to bottom, as soon as a script tag is encountered it gets executed. If the script tag has a link on it that script gets loaded synchronously, holding off rendering of the DOM.

If you absolutely need jQuery to do stuff in the middle of the page, load it on top. Is your webpage now slower? Yeah, it took a second to load jQuery. Were your audience impacted? By how much? a second?

Takeaways: Loading a script at the top is fine. Loading 10 scripts that end up being about 1 mbyte combined is not because it impacts UX.

As other people have mentioned, you can always selectors to manipulate that part of the code, no need to run a script in the middle of the page. It's a better practice to separate your UI from your code anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can defer execution of $ so that your code doesn't run until after your scripts have loaded.

http://www.mrclay.org/2010/11/14/using-jquery-before-its-loaded/